# any way to improve code for menu

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

Hi all I have made a responsive navigation on JSfiddle.

it works well; however I am just wondering whether there is anyway to improve what I have done. I am new at jquery so all help appreciated http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/1540/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $('#menu').animate({
        'left': '0px'
    });
});
$("#close").click(function () {
    $('#menu').animate({
        'left': '-100px'
    });
});
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $('#container').animate({
        'left': '100px'
    });
});
$("#close").click(function () {
    $('#container').animate({
        'left': '0px'
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Since there is no actual *problem* with the supplied code, I feel that this post would be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. `"Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code."`

Comment: Ah didn't know about that one

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a code review.

Comment: No worries, @jon! Looks like this post will eventually be closed though...

Comment: That's fine ill find the other site

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/1545/

Answer (score 0):

Straight away you can remove two of the click handlers and combine their actions: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kX7b6/1543/

Also you do not need to use `px` string values with `animate`. Pixels are assumed for numbers:

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $('#menu').animate({
        'left': 0
    });
    $('#container').animate({
        'left': 100
    });
});
$("#close").click(function () {
    $('#menu').animate({
        'left': -100
    });
    $('#container').animate({
        'left': 0
    });
});
```

Comment: So simple haha. What about variables ? Worth using

Comment: Id based selectors are `very` fast, as they use a browser lookup table, so not really. If you just mean for the values (+/- n) then sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is one Simple problem in the upper code.(Only If you are interested in functionality. Else ignore this please)

Try this :

1. Click Menu and open the side MEnu.
2. Now click 'MEnu' link again for about 10 times.
3. Now click the 'close' link in the opened Menu Bar.

   **Expected Result** :  Menu bar Will be closed.

   **Actual Result** : This will not be closed for few seconds.

   **Reason** :  As when you keep clicking on 'menu' link again and again it builds a animation queue, So first that animation queue will be executed and after completion of it.'Close' link animation will be started.

**Solution** :

```
 $(".menu").click(function () {
    $('#menu').stop(true,true).animate({
        'left': 0
    });
    $('#container').stop(true,true).animate({
        'left': 100
    });
});
$("#close").click(function () {
    $('#menu').stop(true,true).animate({
        'left': -100
    });
    $('#container').stop(true,true).animate({
        'left': 0
    });
});
```

Clear the animation queue with .stop(true,true) once it done.

Here is the link for api [jQuery stop() Api](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Wow this is really good. I guess i could also  do something similar and only have one menu button with and if else statement maybe....